# make clickable layout inflater?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, layout-inflater

I'm using this code to open a Activity by inflating the layout
but the buttons that are contained within the activity are not  clicked, it is as if the task is not called correctly, you can modify this code? or you must use another method?
Thanks in advance,
Code:

Edit by answer

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.disclamer, null); cp = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
        Button mydisclamer = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.binfo);

        mydisclamer.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){ //problem at this line


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub





            if (click){
                cp.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                cp.update(0,0,500,500);
                click=false;
            }else{
                cp.dismiss();
                click=true;
            }
        }
        });
```

Error logcat:

```
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.bizzsound1/org.bizzsound1.menu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at org.bizzsound1.menu.onCreate(menu.java:117)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
12-06 15:00:25.608: E/AndroidRuntime(2891):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have just find your button id by this:

```
 Button  mydisclamer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.binfo);
```

and your button is in your PopUp inflated view..

Change with this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater 
 = (LayoutInflater)this
  .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.disclamer, null);  
         cp = new PopupWindow(
           popupView, 
           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

So change it with:

```
Button mydisclamer = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.binfo);
```

Comment: as highlighted in the code, however mydisclamer.setOnClickListener (new Button.OnClickListener () {

Comment: is button is in disclamer layout??

Comment: oh...so you have to remove popupview from Button mydisclamer = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.binfo);

Comment: finally you can go with this: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html

Comment: I changed in this Button mydisclamer = (Button) findViewById (R.id.binfo) because otherwise you can not call the layout. but do not work equally buttons in the layout

Comment: No..worry..if i have time tomorrow..i will fix it..time to leave.

Comment: ahhh the example made ​​me realize that the buttons must be called in the same activity to inflate the layout. so there is a way to make them work if they are not contained in the same activity?

Answer (score 0):

add this line `Button  mydisclamer = (Button)cp.findViewById(R.id.binfo);`

Comment: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type PopupWindow?